# How to solve first order ODE equations of motion with given init

Tags: python, eclipse-kepler, newtons-method, runge-kutta, first-order-logic

I have converted an equation to the first order ODE and now i would like to solve the motion equations for multiple periods with given conditions.

The equations shall be solved with the following 0 values:
x(0), y(0), vx(0), vy(0) = 3, 1, 2, 1.3 × π

This is the first order ODE, derived from motion equation of Newton's gravitational law for cellestial bodies:

[image]

How can I solve this in python? Could I use Runge Kutta or Keplers methods? I feel like I'm doing something wrong

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

g = 6.674 * 10**(-11)
M = 4*(math.pi**2)/g
x0 = 3 #x-position of the center or h
y0 = 1 #y-position of the center or k
vx0 = 2
vy0 = 1.3* math.pi

#Trying second order
def RK2(y0, f, tlist):
    t = [tlist[0]]
    tf = tlist[1]
    dt = tlist[2]
    
    y = [y0]
  
    while t[-1] < tf:
        k1 = dt * f(y[-1],t[-1])
        k2 = dt * f(y[-1]+0.5*k1 , t[-1]+0.5*dt) ##Take half step
        
        y.append( y[-1] + k2 )
        t.append(t[-1] + dt)
    return(np.array(y), np.array(t) )
```

Comment: take a look at the documentation for `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`